# Keep data in a variable after deletion of an object in Django

Tags: python, django

I am on Django 1.9

I would like to keep a list of ids after I deleted the objects having these ids (to be sent back to an Ajax function).

But because I delete these objects, the list is also emptied.

Here is my code:

```
relatedsteps = Step.objects.filter(theplace=theplaceclicked)
listofrelatedstepsid = relatedsteps.values('id')
response_data = {}
response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'] = listofrelatedstepsid
print(response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'])
relatedsteps.delete()
print(response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'])
```

The first

```
print(response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'])
```

returns

```
[{u'id': 589}]
```

But the second one returns:

```
[]
```

Any clue? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

> values(*fields)
>
> Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that
>   **returns dictionaries when used as an iterable**, rather than
>   model-instance objects.

So to fix your problem you have to use `relatedsteps.values('id')` as iterable, calling [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) or [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) on it is completely fine for you:

```
response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'] = list(listofrelatedstepsid)

print(response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'])
relatedsteps.delete()
print(response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'])
```

Comment: You don't have to use `copy`.

Answer (score 1):

`QuerySet.values` does not actually return a list, it returns a clone of the queryset. Each time you iterate on it (e.g. what `print` does) it hits the db, so the second print re-executes the query after `delete`.

What you should do instead is:

```
response_data['listofrelatedstepsid'] = list(listofrelatedstepsid)
```